# Turning HTML generated from gmplot into the actual map

Tags: python, html, google-maps

Afternoon,

I am trying to use the gmplot library to plot a load of lats/long coordinates I have. If I just take the example on the pypi page, see below (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmplot/1.0.5) and run it, I generate the HTML file but I don't know how to turn this into the actual map. Any ideas?

```
gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(37.428, -122.145, 16)

gmap.plot(latitudes, longitudes, 'cornflowerblue', edge_width=10)
gmap.scatter(more_lats, more_lngs, '#3B0B39', size=40, marker=False)
gmap.scatter(marker_lats, marker_lngs, 'k', marker=True)
gmap.heatmap(heat_lats, heat_lngs)

gmap.draw("mymap.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gmap.draw("mymap.html")
```

This will generate the map in your folder where your notebook is, or your file where you have written the code. If you want the map to be generated at some other location specify the path at `gmap.draw(<path for map>)`.
This map can be opened in any browser. Generated map by gmplot has javascript based zoomin capability and the entire map can be accessed through the browser